# Pure Android phone with the best (glass?) camera lenses

Tags: android, camera

I need an Android phone:

- With virtually indestructible, scratch-proof camera lenses,
- That will be the best for shooting both scenic outdoor and close-up indoor photos.

Price doesn't count and it doesn't have to be a brand new model.

Additional requirements:

- As pure Android as possible (as little "uninstallable apps" as possible)
- MHL / HDMI support, if possible

My recent researches has narrowed the list down to:

- Samsung Galaxy S20 Ultra or Samsung Galaxy S21 FE / Ultra or Samsung Galaxy S22 / S22 Ultra
- Google Pixel 6a or Google Pixel 6 Pro
- Sony Xperia Pro-i
- Xiaomi Mi 10
- Samsung Galaxy Note 20 Ultra
- OPPO Find X2 Pro
- Google Pixel 4A

Though my sources ([1](https://www.pcmag.com/picks/the-best-camera-phones), [2](https://www.godigit.com/mobile-insurance/find/best-camera-phones), [3](https://www.cnet.com/tech/mobile/samsungs-next-phones-will-have-scratch-and-reflection-resistant-cameras-with-corning-dx-plus-tech/) and [4](https://nokiamob.net/2021/11/16/almost-all-smartphone-camera-lenses-are-plastic/)) wasn't enough to tell me which of above (if any) has a pure Android system or MHL/HDMI support.

I know that world-best mobile phone for shooting photos is currently probably any iPhone, but for my private reasons I don't consider this brand.

If possible (other manufacturers offers clean or no-forced-apps Android), I'd like to avoid Google products, because I don't like and don't trust this company.

Comment: Android ***is*** Google. If you don't trust them at all, buy an iPhone.

Comment: I don't trust Apple even more than Google, so this is a choice between bad and even worse.

Comment: Which to trust - a company whose entire business model is based on selling advertising to people interested in your online habits; or one whose entire business model is based on selling you next year's hardware. I know which I'd pick, every time.

Comment: There's still Microsoft.